# Error sending dateTimeRange flight filters on request

Tags: api, rest, web-services, amadeus

I am sending a POST request with dateTimeRange filters to get flight offers on a particular time range.

When I use the departureDateTimeRange OR arrivalDateTimeRange, the response is working fine and returning the flights filtered by the departure/arrival time ranges that I have defined

```
{
"currencyCode": "EUR",
"originDestinations": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "originLocationCode": "OPO",
        "destinationLocationCode": "FNC",
        "arrivalDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2020-07-23",
            "time": "21:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "2H",
            "dateWindow": "P1D"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "originLocationCode": "FNC",
        "destinationLocationCode": "OPO",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2020-07-24",
            "time": "08:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "1H",
            "dateWindow": "P1D"
        }
    }
],
"travelers": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
],
"sources": [
    "GDS"
],
"searchCriteria": {
    "flightFilters": {
        "cabinRestrictions": [
            {
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "coverage": "ALL_SEGMENTS",
                "originDestinationIds": [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "connectionRestriction": {
            "maxNumberOfConnections": 2
        }
    },
    "pricingOptions": {
        "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
    }
}
```

}

But I'd like to filter the Departure time AND the Arrival time altogether... let's pretend I want to departure between 07:00h and 09:00h, and arrive between 08:00h and 09:00h, in a 1 hour flight.

```
{
"currencyCode": "EUR",
"originDestinations": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "originLocationCode": "OPO",
        "destinationLocationCode": "LIS",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2020-07-23",
            "time": "08:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "1H",
            "dateWindow": "P1D"
        },
        "arrivalDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2020-07-23",
            "time": "09:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "1H",
            "dateWindow": "P1D"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "originLocationCode": "LIS",
        "destinationLocationCode": "OPO",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2020-07-24",
            "time": "08:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "1H",
            "dateWindow": "P1D"
        },
        "arrivalDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2020-07-24",
            "time": "09:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "1H",
            "dateWindow": "P1D"
        }
    }
],
"travelers": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
],
"sources": [
    "GDS"
],
"searchCriteria": {
    "flightFilters": {
        "cabinRestrictions": [
            {
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "coverage": "ALL_SEGMENTS",
                "originDestinationIds": [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "connectionRestriction": {
            "maxNumberOfConnections": 2
        }
    },
    "pricingOptions": {
        "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
    }
}
```

The response is an error:

```
"errors": [
{
  "code": 2668,
  "title": "PARAMETER COMBINATION INVALID/RESTRICTED",
  "detail": "departureDateTimeRange and arrivalDateTimeRange are not compatible",
  "source": {
    "pointer": "/originDestinations[0]"
  },
  "status": 400
},
{
  "code": 2668,
  "title": "PARAMETER COMBINATION INVALID/RESTRICTED",
  "detail": "departureDateTimeRange and arrivalDateTimeRange are not compatible",
  "source": {
    "pointer": "/originDestinations[1]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

]

Does this actually mean that I cannot, at all, combine departureTimeRange and arrivalDateTimeRange on the same request, or am I doing something wrong/missing something here on the request details?

Thank you!

Comment: That is correct Francisco, departureDateTimeRange and arrivalDateTimeRange are mutually exclusive and cannot be combined together.

Comment: Thank you @alnacle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The Flight Offers Search API doesn't allow you to search by using both the `departureTimeRange` AND the `arrivalDateTimeRange`, you can use one or the other feature. The logic behind is to return all the flights available to either leave at a specific time or to arrive at the destination at a specific time.

If you want to check the departureTime **AND** the arrivalTime you need to use `departureTimeRange` and filter in the response the arrivalTime.

If you want to have the list of flights that either leave at a specific time **OR** arrive at a specific time then you need to call the API twice using once `departureTimeRange` and the other one `arrivalDateTimeRange`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and useful reply, Anthony. Keep up the good work !